# On hovering a button make tooltip clickable in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a section that has buttons, which are added dynamically, now I want to hover the button to show the tooltip.

When I hover the button and try to click the tooltip it disappear

Here is CSS

```
.point-box:hover + .tooltip-box{
    display: block;
 }
```

Here is HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of draggableElements">
    <div
      class="point-box"
      (cdkDragEnded)="onCircleButtonDragEnd(item)"
      cdkDragBoundary=".image-edit"
      cdkDrag
      [style.left.%]="item.x"
      [style.top.%]="item.y"
      [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
      [id]="'button-' + item.button_id"
      (mouseenter)="onButtonHover(item.button_id)"
    >
      button
    </div>
    <div 
      [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
      class="tooltip-box"
      [class.clicked]="tooltipClicked"
      [id]="'tooltip-' + item.button_id"
      (click)="onTooltipClick(item.button_id)"
      (mouseenter)="onTooltipMouseEnter(item.button_id)"
      (mouseleave)="onTooltipMouseLeave(item.button_id)"
      *ngIf="tooltipVisible[item.button_id]"
      >
      tooltip
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is TS

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

interface DraggableElement {
  button_id: string;
  button_type: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  color: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-editor',
  templateUrl: './page-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-editor.component.scss'],
})

export class PageEditorComponent {
  @ViewChild('tooltip', { static: false }) tooltip: ElementRef | undefined;
  draggableElements: DraggableElement[] = [];
  tooltipVisible: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};
  currentTooltipIndex: number | null = null;
  tooltipClicked: boolean = false;

  constructor(){};

  onButtonHover(index: string): void {
    this.tooltipVisible[index] = true;
  }
  
  onTooltipClick(index: string): void {
    this.tooltipClicked = !this.tooltipClicked;
  }
  
  onTooltipMouseLeave(index: string): void {
    this.tooltipVisible[index] = false;
  }
  
  onTooltipMouseEnter(index: string): void {
    this.tooltipVisible[index] = true;
  }
  
}
```

On hovering the button user should be able to click the tooltip

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. I have test your code and the tooltip don't disappear if I click on it. What is your exact goal?

Comment: @Flo can you provide a link to your working demo? the expected behaviour is when you hover over buttons you should be able to click the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

To allow the tooltip to stay visible when you hover over it, you will need to adjust the way your tooltip is displayed. Currently, it disappears because the hover state is lost when you move the mouse off the button.

To fix this, you can group the button and its corresponding tooltip inside a container div. This way, as long as the hover state is active on the container, the tooltip will remain visible, allowing users to interact with it.

Here is how you can update your HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of draggableElements">
  <div class="container" 
       [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
       (mouseenter)="onContainerMouseEnter(item.button_id)"
       (mouseleave)="onContainerMouseLeave(item.button_id)"
  >
    <div
      class="point-box"
      (cdkDragEnded)="onCircleButtonDragEnd(item)"
      cdkDragBoundary=".image-edit"
      cdkDrag
      [style.left.%]="item.x"
      [style.top.%]="item.y"
      [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
      [id]="'button-' + item.button_id"
    >
      button
    </div>
    <div 
      [attr.data-id]="item.button_id"
      class="tooltip-box"
      [class.clicked]="tooltipClicked"
      [id]="'tooltip-' + item.button_id"
      (click)="onTooltipClick(item.button_id)"
      *ngIf="tooltipVisible[item.button_id]"
    >
      tooltip
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And update your component TypeScript file to handle the **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events on the container:

```
onContainerMouseEnter(index: string): void {
  this.tooltipVisible[index] = true;
}

onContainerMouseLeave(index: string): void {
  this.tooltipVisible[index] = false;
}
```

Lastly, remove the unused methods **onButtonHover**, **onTooltipMouseEnter**, and **onTooltipMouseLeave** as they are no longer needed.

With these changes, the tooltip should remain visible when hovering over the container, allowing users to interact with it. Adjustments may be needed based on your specific requirements and styles, but this should set you on the right path.